# sbt native packager doesn't create scripts under target/universal/stage/bin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to use JavaAppPackaging from sbt-native-packager. My understanding is, that when I run:

`sbt stage`

I should get a directory target/universal/stage/bin with some startup scripts. Now I only get lib which contains my jar and it's dependencies.

Here's the relevant parts of my build.sbt:

```
val scalatra = "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.3.1"

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "myapp",
    version := "0.2",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
    libraryDependencies += scalatra
  )
```

Also, my plugins.sbt has this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0")
```

I'm using sbt 0.13.8.

So why don't I get the startup scripts, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need make sure sbt finds a main for the script.

This could mean either make sure you have a main: an object that `extends App` or one that defines a `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit`.

Otherwise try setting `mainClass`, like so:

```
 mainClass in Compile := Some("JettyLauncher")
```

Comment: I have a class with main. Do I have to tell sbt which one is it somehow?

Comment: At least this didn't help: mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("JettyLauncher")

Comment: @auramo Hmm ok, then you need to provide more detail as with what you have currently + a simple App `stage` will generate the scripts.

Comment: Changed it to mainClass in (Compile) := Some("JettyLauncher"), and ran sbt clean, then sbt stage. Now it worked! Don't know which of the changes did the trick. Anyway, thanks for setting me on the right path!

Comment: `mainClass in (Compile, run)` sets the main class only in the Compile-Configuration _and_ during the `run` task. When you run the `stage` task there is still no main class set.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the main class without any scopes: `mainClass := Some ("full.path.to.MainApp")`